# Installing Web3j CLI tools

Tags: android, command-line-interface, command-prompt, ethereum, web3-java

this question may seem a bit trivial but I can not seem to find how to get it done. I am trying to install web3j CLI tools and I am not sure how to. I have downloaded the latest release from [here](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/releases/tag/v3.4.0) as a zip file. I have tried installing using windows cmd prompt but I am not sure what commands to write. If it is not supposed to be installed with cmd prompt then what should I use?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in this link: [Web3J CLI github](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/README.rst)
**ALWAYS** remember to read the Readme file ^^, scroll down a little everything is explained.

Comment: Hi @xoxel, I did read that page carefully and I also looked at [this one](https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html) carefully but I still unsure of how to install web3j cli tools and use them. I tried even taking the libs out of the zip file I got and adding it as libs in the android project. web3j is always an unrecognized command. Should I not be using normal windows cmd prompt?

Comment: Hmm... did you add the dependencies to your project ? aswell as the compile statement to your gradle ?

Comment: Yes I added them in the libs folder and added :" implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" to my dependencies. I am really new to CLI and feel I may be missing something quite simple. Could you just casually mention like the usual steps of attempting to install the CLI tools?

Comment: Never done such thing, but i used a tons of external libraries myself, also this is what i'am talking about when asking for the dependencies: 
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1-android</version>
</dependency>`

This should be in your project's parameters file

Comment: To be honest i feel a little bit confused, what are you asking exactly, i assumed (looking a the tags) that you wanted to add this library to some android studio project, but if you want to simply install it on your computer then it's different

Comment: I want to install the web3j command line tools to be able to make CLI commands such as [here](https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html) and also those commands that are in the read me such as this command `$ web3j truffle generate /path/to/<truffle-smart-contract-output>.json -o /path/to/src/main/java -p com.your.organisation.name` and other commands in the [Readme link](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/README.rst). Sorry If I am confusing you.

Comment: Okay !! So that's not what i was directing you towards... What you should do is simply extract the zip archive you've downloaded, go into it's folder and then you'll be able to launch commands from there. If you want to be able to do it from everywhere you'll need to work around with paths a lil bit (or aliases if you're lazy) but that's a completely different topic that i won't answer here (sorry) ^^

Comment: Alright @xoxel, thank you for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

for Windows use:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/web3j/web3j-installer/master/installer.ps1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux:

=============================

```
 curl -L get.web3j.io | sh
```

=============================

PS Just read the question and saw that you asked for Windows. Sorry for not answering it, however, maybe it will work if you install CURL and set the Environment Variables, restart if necessary, and then simply run it from a command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to the Internet. Then install node.js and configure it properly.
Open command prompt in Windows and type,

```sh
npm install -g we3j
```

That's it.